# User defined function for SQLite on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, function, geocoding

I'm working on the n'th application locating zip's. Everything works fine in PHP while I worked along the docu on OpenGeoDB. Now, I'm trying the implementation on the iPhone-SDK, but SQLite doesn't have the ACOS, SIN etc funcs.
Can anybody point me to an example of how to expand the SQLite with userfunctions in order to use them in a select?

Any hints appreciated!

Thanx and happy coding!
Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one clears it up pretty nicely:

http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3_create_function(database, "yourAwesome", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &yourAwesomeFunc, NULL, NULL);
```